# Storing and processing large amount of data in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

How can I efficiently store and process data for this problem?

## **Problem Statement**

We have two arrays a and b of length N, initially all values equals to zero. We have Q operation. Let's define three types of operations on this arrays:

`1 l r c`:Increase al,a(l+1),...,ar by c.

`2 l r c`:Increase bl,b(l+1),...,br by c.

`3 l r`:Print (al∗bl) + a(l+1)∗b(l+1) +...+ (ar∗br) in modulo 1000000007.

## **Input Format**

First line of the input consists of N and Q. Next Q lines contain one of the three types of operations.

## **Constraints**

1 ≤ N ≤ 10^9
1 ≤ Q ≤ 200000
1 ≤ c ≤ 10000
1 ≤ l ≤ r ≤ N

## **Output Format**

Whenever you get a type 3 operation, you should print the answer in a new line.

**Sample Input**

```
5 3 
1 1 5 5 
2 2 4 2 
3 3 4
```

**Sample Output**

```
20
```

## **My code in C**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    long n,q,ch,l,r,c,i,j;
    /* n, q, l, r, c works as per problem statement.
       ch is used to scan the first digit of operation.
       i and j are used to control the loops. */
    scanf("%ld %ld",&n,&q);
    long a[n],b[n];
    memset(&a, 0, sizeof a);
    memset(&b, 0, sizeof b);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)    //Init to 0
    {
        a[i]=0;
        b[i]=0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        scanf("%ld ",&ch);  //Look for the first digit
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
                scanf("%ld %ld %ld",&l,&r,&c);
                l--;
                for(j=l;j<r;j++)
                    a[j]+=c;    //Adds c to every element of a
                break;
            case 2:
                scanf("%ld %ld %ld",&l,&r,&c);
                l--;
                for(j=l;j<r;j++)
                    b[j]+=c;    //Adds c to every element of b
                break;
            case 3:
                scanf("%ld %ld",&l,&r);
                l--;
                c=0;
                for(j=l;j<r;j++)
                    c+=a[j]*b[j];   //Adds the product
                printf("%ld\n",c%1000000007);   //Prints the value after using mod
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You got a problem with the code? Then describe it more thorough, please. You want to know a more efficient way of accomplishing that? Ask the question on Code Review.

Comment: And note that identifiersx can have more than 2 characters, so use expressive names. And line-comments are there for a reason.

Comment: HINT: storing 2 int arrays of size 1000000000 in automatic storage will probably *not* work.

Comment: I am sorry. I have added the comments and also the description of the variables.

Comment: I am stuck on how to store 2 arrays of size 10^9 bytes each.

Comment: And you expect the user to enter them? Wow!

Comment: The approach for the arrays that I would take is to use the `malloc()` function to allocate the memory on the heap. 10^9 bytes is 1 billion bytes or 1 gig of memory so it may fit with two arrays of that size. However an int is either 4 bytes or 8 bytes depending on marchine architecture so the question is whether you have a 64 bit or 32 bit OS and application. However I just tried it with Visual Studio 2005 with Windows 7 64 bit, 16GB RAM. Simple console application and the second `malloc()` failed with a NULL pointer though the first succeeded probably because of being a 32 bit application.

Comment: @Olaf: User doesn't need to enter anything. Black box testing is being used here.

Comment: @RichardChambers: Could you please tell me how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Hint: you don't need to store the arrays, just ranges within them.

Comment: @RichardChambers: `malloc` returning non-NULL does not necessarily mean all memory is really available.

Comment: @wildplasser: Could you please elaborate on that? How do I multiply and add the numbers if the numbers aren't stored?

Comment: You just store the (accumulated c) values for a and b once for every range of indexes. When multiplying, you should scale by the width of this range. (taking care of possible overflow)

Comment: @SomnathRakshit - You are computing the values of the arrays somehow. How about delaying these computations until you need to use the values? Then perhaps you don't need to store all of them at the same time?

Comment: But does this improve the time cost?

Comment: @BoPersson: Could you please be a little more clearer? I didn't quite get you. I'm new to programming.

Comment: @SomnathRakshit - Its just a general hint. It you don't need all the values at the same time, you might be able to compute some of them just when they are needed. Saves you from using GBs of storage. When multiplying `a[j]` and `b[j]`, could you figure out what those values would be *right there*? If so, you don't have to store them

Comment: @BoPersson: How do I figure out what those values would be right there?

Comment: What do I do if I need to perform the 3rd operation after a million 1st or 2nd operations? How do I multiply after adding c if I don't store it in this way?

Comment: @SomnathRakshit I sugest you use paper and pencil and work out your sample input `1 1 5 5 // 2 2 4 2 // 3 3 4` by hand. You'll probably see the solution then. (otherwise, try again with `1 10 50 5 // 2 20 40 2 // 3 30 40` )

Comment: @wildplasser: But what if I have another 10 or so 1st and 2nd operations after this and then one more 3rd operation from 20 to 30?

Comment: Just make the drawing, and do the math.

Comment: @wildplasser: I did. But I can't figure out an answer to my question that I just commented.

Comment: Your blocks will get more and more fragmented if you do more operations. But you still have blocks.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/104515/9357)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I efficiently store and process data for this problem?

For N = 10<sup>9</sup> you have to store about 7.4 GB data, if you merely use longs with a size of 4 bytes.

This is not feasible, which, I assume, is the whole point of the problem.

You have 200000 Qs - storing the Qs instead takes up only 11 bytes per Q - one byte to determine the operation, 8 bytes for the two values which can go up to 10<sup>9</sup>and 2 bytes for c, which fits into 16 bits, as it's not higher than 10000.

If you store Q, you end up with around 2 MB of data.

You could apply the Q operations at runtime to a single long (long) and then print each value individually. This algorithm will be memory-efficient, but very very slow.

Looking at the problem, we will have a lot of array members having the same value. There are only 200000 operations but 1000000000 array entries - we can change 200000 different values - if we do this, we still have (10<sup>9</sup> - 200000) array entries with the very same value. Even if we modify 200000 ranges, this doesn't change the fact, merely the distribution of distinct values. So it's much more efficient to store a value and then for which array range this value is valid.

In example:

```
value 0 - [0,4343] [489289,999999999]
value 3 - [4344,4345]
value 7 - [4346,489288]
```

This is a mixture of storing the value and storing the operation. When you need to print a value, you look up the range and print the value.

As you see, we need less than 64 bytes for this simple example to store the information how the 7.4 GB data is compromised of, yet we can print the value for each and every array position.

Even if we have reduced the data, we still need to optimize the remaining data. We can't just dump it into a linked list - as stated, we can end up with Q+1 entries (200001), we can't afford to search the entries with an effort of O(n), let alone (r-l) * O(n).

But if we put the data into a binary search tree, we can find the correct array entry in 18 steps within the 200000 entries. This costs us some more memory, not only due to the overhead, but as we need the array index as key, we can't group all identical values together, just as long as they are one range. So the example above will need 4 nodes in the binary search tree, to separate the value 0 twice.

So, when you combine these two approaches, you should be able to get a decent memory and processor time consumption.